# Radial gradient on IOS creates a visual artefact

Tags: html, css, ios, webkit, web-frontend

[image]

[image]

As shown in the images the radial gradient produces visual artefact, i'm using it as a mask to produce ios like effect.

```
    background:-webkit-radial-gradient(transparent 0%,transparent 30%,white 32%);
    background:-o-radial-gradient(transparent 0%,transparent 30%,white 32%);
    background:radial-gradient(transparent 0%,transparent 30%,white 32%);
```

Answer (score 0):

transparent does not work with ios, replaced with rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) and it worked fine